# Is there any difference between to strew and to scatter?

Tags: differences, synonyms

I just read that :

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/strew-scatter.172228/

and it appears those two words are interchangeable, apart that strew is rather literate.

What do you think?

Comment: "Strew" implies "slinging" the stuff as it is being scattered.

Comment: Strewn connotes more of a mess than scattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in many cases you can use either word, there are some quirks in usage. According to a [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search:

- *Scatter* is more common than *strew*. (7796 hits versus 126 hits.)
- One is more likely to *strew* flowers or to *strew* something along a path or a way
- One is more likely to *scatter* ashes, light, or the pronoun *them*.

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/191542) confirms the associations between *strew* and plant material as well as surfaces:

> a. transitive. To *scatter*, spread loosely; to scatter (rushes, straw, flowers, etc.) on the ground or floor, or over the surface of something; to sprinkle (something granulated or in powder) over a surface.

Note the use of *scatter* to define the term. The relevant meaning of *[scatter](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/172150)* is very similar:

> a. To throw or send forth so that the particles are distributed or spread about; to sow or throw (seed, money, etc.) broadcast; to sprinkle, *strew*; to diffuse (fragrance).

The difference in this subset of meanings is slight and isn't even about the method of delivery. It's more about the materials involved and the associations with them. Grammatically I wouldn't blink at *scattering flowers* or *strewing ashes*, but on a good day I might notice that the verb doesn't fit expected usage.

---

A final note: *scatter* can be used as an intransitive verb, referring to an action that the subject does to itself. Merriam-Webster on *[scatter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatter)*, intransitive:

> : to separate and go in various directions : disperse
>
> When the weights hit the ground, the marbles scattered.

*[Strew](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strew)* has no such intransitive use. "The marbles strew" does not make sense.

Comment: And of course with human objects, there is a very important difference in meaning: if the troops were scattered on the field, they are running from the enemy – but if they’re _strewn_ on the field, they’re already dead. This ties in with the fact that _scatter_ is also intransitive, since _scatter_ here is really a causative meaning ‘cause to scatter or spread out [agentively]’, which is not possible with _strew_, which has only a patientive meaning.

Comment: hi ! what's the meaning of "the troops were scattered on the field"? i don't understand that sentence. I would rather say it means the troops are dispersed.

Comment: @MarineGalantin - *dispersed* implies intent to distribute. *scattered* just implies randomness.

Comment: But why would they retreat?  Randomess has nothing to do with defeat

Comment: @MarineGalantin - Normally the troops would be in an orderly arrangement on the field; Forming ranks or lines. When the enemy  onslaught is too strong and they are undisciplined, they break ranks and scatter.